# Нейросеть для анализа последовательности чисел и предсказание следующего бинарного числа

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект

На вход должна подаваться бинарная последовательность чисел, состоящая из 50 нулей и единиц. Нужно чтобы нейросеть обучилась на этой последовательности, проанализировала ее и на выходе предсказала следующее число (0 или 1). Посоветуйте,пожалуйста, какие-нибудь статьи или примеры кода.

Comment: Это куда-то в сторону `LSTM`, например. Или `GRU`.

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от природы явления, которое генерирует это последовательность.
Если это просто некий случайный процесс о котором вам вообще ничего не известно, то он моделируется т.н. законом распределения Бернулли. Информацию ищем в любом учебнике по теории вероятности.
Если эта информация моделирует поток событий, то он описывается т.н. потоком Пуассона. Соответствующую информацию можно найти в более "продвинутых" источниках, например

> Кингман Дж. Пуассоновские процессы

.
Смущает то, что у вас на входе только 50 бит информации. По таким данным что-то серьезное (т.е. с достаточно высоким уровнем достоверности прогноза) предсказать невозможно.